# How to ship android app with R script in it and make sure it executes

Tags: java, android, r, machine-learning

I am building one Android machine learning app where in a java class I need to make a call to a R script. But before that I need to make sure that R is up and running. How do I do that? How to get the Rconnection established in android code?

```
  public String getSum() {
    RConnection connection = null;

    try {
        /* Create a connection to Rserve instance running on default port
         * 6311
         */
        connection = new RConnection();
        connection.eval("library(randomForest)");
        /* Note four slashes (\\\\) in the path */
        connection.eval("source('MyScript.R')");

        REXP sum =connection.eval("predictSAL()");
        this.sum = sum.asString();
    } catch (RserveException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (REXPMismatchException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (REngineException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return sum;
}
```